# How to make a scroll list inside text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Can anyone suggest me, I am making an iphone app in which there is a text field  where user has to select option from as list I have used tableView to show the list, and user select any one from them. But I want the text field as scroll Wheel where user can scroll the list inside the textfield and data get selected in the textfield when user stop scrolling as UIDatePicker does.

Please help me.

Comment: How does the user indicate which line of text they want to select, by location like a picker or by touch like a table?  (Also, should I assume you mean text view rather than text field?)

Comment: I want user can select the list like a picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, you should be able to create a UIScrollViewDelegate for your UITextView and implement scrollViewDidScroll:.  Use the contentOffset to figure out what position the user has scrolled to.